# Text moving when browser resized

Tags: html, css

So when I resize my browser the text moves with it in my header, how can I get it to just stick in the place its currently in and not move when browser is resized?

Thanks a lot in advance, I really appreciate everyone's help on here!

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uZDZ/).

Normal
[image: Normal]

Resized
[image: Resized]

HTML:

```
<div id="NewNavBar"><ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="me" style="margin-left:10px;"><b>Home</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="community">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="staff">Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop">Shop</a></li>
        </ul></div>
        </div>

        <div id="NewNavB"><ul class="navb">
        <li><a href="me" style="margin-left:10px;"><b>{username}</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="account">Account Settings</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#NewNavBar {
text-align: center;
position:relative;
width:100%;
min-height:40px;
border-top:2px solid #3f82a3;
border-bottom:2px solid #3977af;
background-color:#529ce2;
line-height: 40px;
}

li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#NewNavBar li + li::before {
    content: " | ";
}

#NewNavB li + li::before {
    content: " | ";
}

li a{
padding:8px;
    }

    #NewNavBar ul a:hover{
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #3f82a3;
    padding: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #4683bc;
}

ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    margin-left:202px;
}

.navb {
    float: left;
    color: #53729c;
    margin-left:202px;
}

#NewNavB {
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:15px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 30px;
border-bottom:2px solid #c1c1c1;
background-color:#f9f9f9;
line-height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Can you put that into jsFiddle or similar? It makes it easier for other users to answer you.

Comment: Hey @John_C I am having a look into it myself, feel free to use my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dNsBe/

Comment: I am not sure I entirely understand the issue. Your nav is in a 100% container so it will always be relative to that. If you don't want it to move on resize you need to give it an explicit pixel width.

Comment: If you want that your nav text not resized then better use "px"

Comment: Sorry jdfiddle has been added by another user, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get something like what you want by specifying the `margin-left` of the two `.nav` and `.navb` in terms of `%` or `vw` (both of these scale better than `px` when the user zooms).  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/y8VXF/), and see [here the full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/y8VXF/embedded/result/).

```
.nav {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    margin-left:25vw;
}
.navb {
    float: left;
    color: #53729c;
    margin-left:25vw;
}
```

But if the user zooms in enough, it's going to break your layout. If you want to, you can specify a media query in terms of `em`s (`max-width: 30em`, e.g.)--which, if done right, can both improve layout upon user zoom and make your site more responsive on mobile screens.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/y8VXF/4/embedded/result/) and ex.:

```
@media (max-width: 30em) {
    .nav {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .navb {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing (apart from some hackish JS) that can prevent it from moving on zoom. Using `%` or `vw` makes it much less noticeable, though, as you can see in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the width of the #NewNavBar in  px instead in percentage.

Comment: It still moves when resized, I tried that before posting this.